# Remove all words from a string that exist in a list

Tags: python, pandas

community.

I need to write a function that goes through a string and checks if each word exists in a list, if the word exists in the (Remove list) it should remove that word if not leave it alone.

i wrote this:

```
def remove_make(x):
    a = x.split()
    for word in a: 
        if word in remove: # True
            a = a.remove(word)  
        else:
            pass
        return a
```

But it returns back the string with the (Remove) word still in there. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to keep a copy of the list and iterate over it, [see top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Can you share a simple data from your file besides you requested answer structure and your tried code??

Comment: For me your question isn't clear. You need to add more information due to the lack of explanation. **Simple data** of your string and the **required** answer which you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something more simple:

```
import re

remove_list = ['abc', 'cde', 'edf']
string = 'abc is walking with cde, wishing good luck to edf.'

''.join([x for x in re.split(r'(\W+)', string) if x not in remove_list])
```

And the result would be:

> ' is walking with , wishing good luck to .'

The important part is the last line:

```
''.join([x for x in re.split(r'(\W+)', string) if x not in remove_list])
```

What it does:

- You are converthing the string to list of words with [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split)(r'(\W+)', string), preserving all the whitespaces and punctuation as list items.
- You are creating another list with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), filtering all the items, which are not in remove_list
- You are converting the result list back to string with [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join)

The BNF notation for list comprehensions and a little bit more information on them may be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

PS: Of course, you may make this a little bit more readable if you break the one-liner into peaces and assign the result of *re.split(r'(\W+)', string)* to a variable and decouple the join and the comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

A more terse way of doing this would be to form a regex alternation based on the list of words to remove, and then do a single regex substitution:

```py
inp = "one two three four"
remove = ['two', 'four']
regex = r'\s*(?:' + r'|'.join(remove) + ')\s*'
out = re.sub(regex, ' ', inp).strip()
print(out)   # prints 'one three'
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.remove(x)` returns `None` and modifies the `list` in-place by removing `x` it exists inside the list. When you do

```
a = a.remove(word)
```

you will be effectively storing `None` in `a` and this would give an exception in the next iteration when you again do `a.remove(word)` (`None.remove(word)` is invalid), but you don’t get that either since you immediately `return` after the conditional (which is wrong, you need to `return` after the loop has finished, outside its scope). This is how your function should look like (without modifying a list while iterating over it):

```
remove_words = ["abc", ...] # your list of words to be removed

def remove_make(x):
    a = x.split()
    temp = a[:]
    for word in temp: 
        if word in remove_words: # True
            a.remove(word)
    # no need of 'else' also, 'return' outside the loop's scope
    return " ".join(a)
```

Comment: Be careful with variable `remove`, because it is not a parameter of the function and it is not definied init as well. And the split can make some trouble, too. If you split "I like you." you get `a=['I', 'like', 'you.']` If you want to remove "you", this will fail.

Comment: Nothing is mentioned regarding the punctuation, I don’t even know how the string is supposed to be created back from the list (they don’t even return a string but the list itself btw), this answer only aims towards fixing the current issue with it, not regarding how to create a correct, sane list back from the split list. If I were to remove the words, I would either use regex or list comprehension instead, which I could’ve mentioned in the answer, but again, that’s not the real issue here. I think question needs more details in that aspect.

Comment: Your are right. But I think it is important to mention that punctuation will have an influence to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new list without the words you want to remove and then use join() function to concatenate all the words in that list. Try

```
def remove_words(string, rmlist):
    final_list = []
    word_list = string.split()
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in rmlist:
            final_list.append(word)
    
    return ' '.join(final_list)
```